# Use custom ProgressDialog during AsyncTask within Adapter

Tags: android, listview, progressdialog, android-arrayadapter

I use an ArrayAdapter to show items in a ListView. Every row in this ListView owns a button.

Whenever the user clicks on one of these buttons I start an AsyncTask to do some processing in the background.

This is working so far.

Now I want to show a custom ProgressDialog during this time. What puzzles me here is the first parameter of the static convinience method ProgressDialog.show(). Within an activity I usually use "Activityname.this" here. But what should I use in an adapter. I tried context from the adapter (that crashed), context.getApplicationContext and several more. Nothing worked - either crashed or is refused from the compiler.

So my question today: What should I put into this parameter?

Here's a stripped down part of my code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyContainer> {

  private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute () {
      if (!isRunning) {
        progressDialog = MyProgressDialog.show(?????,
                                               null,
                                               null,
                                               true,
                                               false);
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... strings) {
      boolean rc = false;

      if (!isRunning) {
        isRunning = true;
        //
        rc = true;
      }

      return rc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
      if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.cancel();
      }
      progressDialog = null;

      //    
    }
  }

  private class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    private MyContainer container; 

    public MyOnClickListener(final MyContainer container) {
      this.container = container;
    }

    public void onClick(final View view) {
      if (container != null) {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(container.getUrl());
      }
  }

  private String                 appName = "";
  private ArrayList<MyContainer> containers;
  private Context                context;
  private boolean                isRunning;
  private int                    layout;
  private MyProgressDialog       progressDialog;
  private Resources              resources;

  public MyAdapter(final Context context, final int layout, final ArrayList<MyContainer> containers, final long link_id) {
    super(context, layout, containers);

    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.containers = containers;

    resources = context.getResources();
    appName = resources.getString(R.string.txt_appname);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, final View contentView, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    //
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Using the instance variable context from the adapter worked after cleaning the project. Arg! Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Did you try Activityname.this

Comment: If it crashed what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi :D well if you see your constructor of adapter

```
public MyAdapter(final Context context, final int layout, final ArrayList<MyContainer> containers, final long link_id) {
    super(context, layout, containers);

    this.context = context;
```

you pass context so in side of adapter you use context :D to build progress dialog